# In case of an intrusion does changing my private ip/lan ip helps?

Tags: security, ip, intrusion-prevention

In case of an intrusion does changing my private ip/lan ip helps ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

> In case of an intrusion does changing my private ip/lan ip helps ?

Does changing your name help if a thief is in your house?  Re-addressing is the last thing I would think about in an intrusion.

Are you assuming you found the intrusion?

If so, then fix the hole the intruder came in and trust *nothing*.  Hard drive firmware, keyboard firmware, almost anything is game if someone gets a good hold in your network.  Hopefully you had backups on offline physical media (CD / DVD / tape) so you know what you can trust.

Depending on the sophistication of the intruder there is no limit to what can be compromised; if they are nation / state-level actors even [routers, switches, or firewall firmware can be hacked](http://leaksource.info/2013/12/30/nsas-ant-division-catalog-of-exploits-for-nearly-every-major-software-hardware-firmware/) (see any number of compromises: BANANAGLEE, HALLUXWATER, JETPLOW, just to name a few).  Quite honestly, if it's a state actor, you're just up a creek; you can't fight people like that.